# How to draw to "parent TLW backing store"?

Tags: c++, qt, window, raster, qnx

This might be very complicated question not many people know answer but I still will ask.

I do have QWindow derived class, with overloaded event(), which uses Backing store and fill in whole window with a colour, let say black.

Now I have my QT QML app, when I create my window and set parent as main view of my app, I getting window sized to 1x1px ! This is driving me crazy..

I dug though the QT source code and found this:

```
void QQnxRasterWindow::adjustBufferSize()
{
// When having a raster window we don't need any buffers, since
// Qt will draw to the parent TLW backing store.
const QSize windowSize = window()->parent() ? QSize(1,1) : window()->size();
if (windowSize != bufferSize())
   setBufferSize(windowSize);
}

void QQnxRasterWindow::setParent(const QPlatformWindow *wnd)
{
    QQnxWindow::setParent(wnd);
    adjustBufferSize();
}
```

Which is kinda bummer because I have no idea how I suppose to use TLW and draw into my window now.
Any ideas?

First of all what is TLW ?
Second how do I draw into parent TLW in a way it will end up in my window buffer.

Thank you

QT 5.3.1

Edit:
not renderNow() - my mistake,
overloaded function event, which uses event UpdateRequested to draw my background.

Edit2:
Also this is only problem when I set parent, when no parent set I can do whatewer I want with my QWindow and it has own buffer. Kinda weird.

Comment: I assume TLW means top-level widget here. IIRC, in Qt's impl for QNX/ libscreen, all Qt windows of a process share a common buffer, so the child window doesn't need its own. I assume your QWindow-derived class breaks some assumptions The Qt/QNX is based on. (What is "overloaded renderNow()" referring to? I don't see that in QWindow) Which QNX/libscreen versions are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why? Doesn't `QPaintDeviceWindow` do what you wish?

Comment: ...and what are you trying to achieve with your custom QWindow? Try if it works with just the QML view (QQuickView?)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I made correction, i talking about event() function
I trying to create new window with window group for other processes windows to join, this window should have certain background
Also it has to be raster window not to engage any EGL stuff and be as light as possible, QQuickView and QuickWindow are heavy.

I did not want to get into details of this as it can be a rat hole to explain, but rougly this is what I wan to do :)

Comment: * "The Qt/QNX is based on” should read “the Qt/QNX implementation of windowing and rendering is based on"

Comment: QPaintDeviceWindow introduced in 5.4.. not going to help me, at least now.

Comment: May be what I want is just plain impossible, and I have to do workaround. IMPOSSIBLE is acceptable answer :)

Comment: Here's what I think: your explanation, due to language barriers, is essentially incomprehensible. Your language lacks the specificity needed in such a question. Thus, please do the other best thing: post a minimal code example that reproduces the issue. There should be exactly three files: main.cpp, main.qml and main.qrc. Do not create any header files, and put all method definitions within class declarations. I have plenty of answers that demonstrate such minimalism.

Comment: Never mind, thank you for helping, also pointing out on crappy language skills. I'd rather attack problem from different angle.